# What Driver IC to use for 40v 2amp DC motor?

Tags: motor

I am using a 40v 2amp 3300rpm DC motor for my motor control project via arduino. But i don't know what driver ic to use for driving the motor.any help would be appreciated..

Comment: One that can drive 40V 2A. This is what parametric searches are for on electronics suppliers - use them. If you can't find a suitable chip then you can always build your own H-bridge from MOSFETs.

Comment: Two minutes with a parametric search told me to use the [L298N](http://uk.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/l298n/ic-bridge-driver-dual-298/dp/403295)

Comment: Looking on eBay they are available for peanuts from China on a handy breakout board for even easier use.

Comment: @Majenko Can i use L298N for direction reversal as well?

Comment: It is a pair of full H-bridges. You can use it to drive two motors in both directions independently. Note that the modules on eBay seem to be limited to 35V because of the 7805 on them. Remove that and you have the full 48V range.

Comment: It's quite hard, on ebay, to find anything but L298N, once the power envelop swells enough :-)

Comment: @Majenko How do i remove 7805..infact what that means?

Comment: @AwaisSaifi There may be a switch or jumpers to do it for you. The 7805 is the 5V regulator on the board - the small black square chip thing that is on most of the breakout boards on eBay. If you do have to remove it (no switch or jumpers) then you would, logically, use a soldering iron.

Comment: @IgorStoppa not just on eBay :-p

Comment: @Majenko I intend to use just the chip not breakout board. Can i do that?

Comment: @AwaisSaifi Yes. In that case you don't have to worry about anything except making sure you have a suitable heatsink.

Comment: On the board I'm using right now, the 7805 is soldered in a not-so-easy-to-reach position and it's flat, it's using the board itself as both ground and heat sink.
In such case I'd cut the 2 pins as close as possible to the resin package, desolder the 2 stumps and wire out to a separate, discrete regulator. For bonus points, mount it upside down on the heatsink, using the same screw  and hole that the L298N is using. This is the board I'm talking about http://www.photo138.com/0/BOB/CEG007200-D-4.JPG

Comment: @Majenko Hmmm and how do i do that. I know i'm being annoying but believe me i'm a beginner and its my final year project and i need all the help i can get and this is the only place.

Comment: @AwaisSaifi Crudely: You buy a big heatsink of the right style and attach it with a bolt through the hole.  In detail: You read the datasheet, calculate the thermal coefficients etc and find the right heatsink to dissipate the desired amount of heat in the environment you are running it in. Look at the ones on eBay - you will see the heatsink. The big lump of metal attached to the chip.

Comment: @IgorStoppa that would be difficult for me as i want it to be simpler.

Comment: @Majenko ok got that.

Comment: I'd think it's simpler to rewire 2 pads than design from scratch the board I linked to. Btw, it's 2-sided and has tracks already routed and designed to cope with the currents involved.

Comment: @IgorStoppa gotta consider both options. you said you would use a seperate regulator, which one to be exact?

Comment: If you check the datasheet for the L298N, it says that the max voltage is 7V, so a 7807 is the simpler choice..
You do not even have to solder anything: as long as you cut the pins of the onboard 7805, you can feed the 7V through the 3rd line of the power connector, which would be usually meant for drawing 5V from the onboard regulator.

Comment: @Majenko what if i use a driver with higher parameters like 50v 3amp? Will it work with my motor?

Comment: @AwaisSaifi Yes, that will be fine. Those are upper limits of what it can handle - more than that and you risk burning out the driver.

Comment: @Majenko Will the motor draw what it needs and not more??

Comment: @AwaisSaifi That is correct. You provide the correct voltage (power supply), the motor draws an amount of current (depending on loading). The driver has to be able to cope with those two values. A bit like a pint of beer. You want a pint of beer, and the bar tender is capable of pouring you a pint of beer. As long as what he pours it into is big enough it won't overflow - whether it's a pint glass, or a flagon, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @IgorStoppa If i am to rewire the regulator, which regulator should i use?

Comment: @AwaisSaifi: did I not answer already?

Comment: @IgorStoppa I'm terribly sorry man. I think i'm overstressed about this project. anyways apologies. :)

Comment: what if i just join the two pins from where i remove the 7805? @IgorStoppa

Comment: If i understood the datasheet correctly, you want the regulated side to be 7V, but joining the 2 voltage domains means that also the input voltage must be 7V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming since you did not state anything differently you simply want to turn it on or off and possibly PWM to control speed of the motor.  By far the easiest way is to simply use a N-Channel logic level MOSFET.  Connect the Arduino pin of your choice through a 51 (1) ohm resistor to the gate of the MOSFET, also Connect a 10K (2) resistor from the same microprocessor (Arduino) pin to ground.  The "Ground" low side of the 40V power supply needs to be connected to the low side of the Arduino.  The low side of the 40V power supply must be connected to the source of the MOSFET.

Connect the motor from the plus side of the 40V power supply (this will be removed for testing) to the Drain of the N-Channel MOSFET. Last and very important place a diode rated at least 2 amps at 60 volts from the positive side of the poser supply (cathode of the diode, with the band) to the Drain of the MOSFET (anode, no band).

Carefully check your wiring; if it is ok you are ready to test it.  The safest way is to use a led with a 510 ohm in series with the cathode on the Arduino +5 with the positive side of the 40v power supply disconnected.  The anode side connects to the drain of the MOSFET.  When the motor is turned on the LED will light, if it does not reverse polarity of the LED.  As tempting as it might be do not leave the LED connected to the Arduino when the motor is connected.  Up the value of the resistor to about 5.6K and connect it across the motor, it will light when the motor is on.

1. This helps dampen oscillations
2. Since the Arduino initializes with all pins as inputs this can drift high, this solves that potential problem which would cause the MOSFET to turn on.
3. For the MOSFET you need at least 60V with a 10A rating.  This should work with a small heat sink.  If you go to a higher amp rating on the MOSFET it will operate cooler.

Output of Arduino goes to 10K to ground and to a 51 ohm resistor (1/8 W or larger)
The other side of the resistor goes to the gate of the MOSFET.
Ground of the motor power supply, the Arduino and the Source of the MOSFET are connected together.  The 2A diode is connected with the cathode (no band) to the drain of the MOSFET, the cathode (band) is connected to the +40V.  The motor connects from the +40 to the Drain of the MOSFET, reversing the leads will probably reverse motor direction.

Good Luck,
Gil